# How to fix screen back to its standard font size on R?

Tags: r, screen-size

I accidentally made everything smaller by typing something, probably alt + a mysterious key. How do I change it back? Everything is too small to read now :(
It looks like this

[image: 1]

Comment: Do mean **R** or **RStudio**? If Rstudio, press `Ctrl` + `+`.

Comment: Thanks! I meant RStudio, it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I fixed it. For those facing the same problem: there's the "Zoom In" on the View menu, and also the "Actual Size" - that fixes it back to the usual standards.